# To fix an error like 'cannot implicitly convert type object to string'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am using a class in [asp](/questions/tagged/asp) project. But I am facing sql error
an duse this code

```
public string GetScalerValue(string Qstr)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = Qstr;
    cmd.Connection = constr;
    string retvalue = null;
    try
    {
        CreateConn();
        retvalue = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        CloseConn();
    }
    return retvalue;
}
```

on `cmd.ExecuteScalar();`
it produce this error.

Comment: `return ex.Message;` sounds ridiculous to me. Consider `GetScalerValue("select username from blah blah")` and it returns "Connection could not be made" or whatever.. ?

Answer (score 4):

If your first column is a `varchar` or similar column `ExecuteScalar()` could potentally return 3 different things.

1. A string, whatever value was in the database
2. `null`, this represents no rows where returned by the query
3. `DbNull.Value`, this represents that rows where returned but the value was `NULL` in sql.

Because the object returned could be of type `string` or of type `DbNull` it has to return `object` as that is the most common type that can hold both objects.

If you know your query will always return rows and may or may not be `NULL` you can just use the `as` operator to cast it.

```
retvalue = cmd.ExecuteScalar() as string;
```

If you want more elaborate logic you can do that do

```
object temp = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
if(temp == null)
{
    //Do something special because no rows where returned
}
else if(temp == DbNull.Value)
{
    //Do something special because the string was NULL in sql
}
else
{
    retvalue = (string)temp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you neeed to convert it to string.

Do this `retvalue = cmdExecuteScalar().ToString()`

(or)

cast it.  `retvalue = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();`

`ExecuteScalar` returns you `object`, which you have to convert to string either by casting or using `.ToString();`

Use `cmd.ExecuteScalar() as string;` as it is more robust. Will not throw `InvalidCastException` and instead returns you `null`

Comment: `(string)cmd.ExecuteScalar()` will fail if the value returned was `NULL` in sql with a invalid cast exception. `cmd.ExecuteScalar() as string;` will just return `null` and `.ToString()` will return a empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Because `ExecuteScalar` returns an `object` you have to cast it to `string`:

```
retvalue = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Answer (score 0):

cmd.ExecuteScalar() function will return the "object" type. You can't assign it to any other type without explicitly cast. So changing the below code will fix the error

```
retvalue = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

-Ganesh